# Image Stitching using EMGU CV

Tags: image-processing, image-stitching

I would like to do image stitching to produce a panoramic view image at one position roughly 360 degrees. For now my coding is like this...

### this is the capture while stitching button coding

```
        int n = 1;
        String fileName;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.4/view/snapshot.shtml?picturepath=/jpg/image.jpg");
        res = request.GetResponse();//.GetResponse();
        string[] CapturedImage = new string[28];
        Image<Bgr, Byte>[] TotalImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>[28];
        do
        {
            fileName = @"D:\Ervin Loong (116834P)\Program Testing\Images\" + "Image" + (n++) + ".jpg"; // File location & Filename.
        }
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)); // check for existing previously saved files. If yes, add another new picture.
        {
            AMCLiveFeed.SaveCurrentImage(0, fileName);
            res.Close();
        }
        if (n == 29)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) // i < 10 - save 10 images
            {
                CapturedImage[i] = @"D:\Ervin Loong (116834P)\Program Testing\Images\" + "Image" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
                TotalImage[i] = new Image<Bgr, byte>(CapturedImage[i]);
            }

            try
            { 
                using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(false)) //Although the Stitcher class is built for GPU acceleration, a false flag must be passed to enable CPU processing. As GPU is not implemented yet.
                {
                    Image<Bgr, Byte> CapturedResult = stitcher.Stitch(TotalImage);
                    IMGBXDisplayStitched.Image = CapturedResult; //imagebox displays stitched results.
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                foreach (Image<Bgr, Byte> DisposeImage in TotalImage)
                {
                    DisposeImage.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: currently this program only can stitch horizontally but not vertically and when it tries to stitch vertically, open cv :unable to allocate ____ bytes error will occur so how do I solve it?

Comment: Your question is probably not detailed enough. Tell us a bit more about the code: where does `TotalImage` come from? What makes you think it can only stitch horizontally? Did you make tests? Do you have screenshots to show us?

Comment: I have added on the coding into the main thread, see if you can understand, but for the screenshot, I am unable to unload it from my computer.